# How can I hide related questions section in all sites?

Tags: support, design, user-interface, mobile-web

I suppose this is trivial, but my Google searching didn't yield any solution.

I suppose you all know what "related questions" means, the section of the sidebar (or middle bar) that displays links to other questions that are supposed to be relevant to the current question and useful to the reader.

But more often than not, in fact in my experience the related questions are almost always completely unrelated to the current question and aren't about the same topic as the current question at all. The only similarity may be one or two shared tags.

The section serves only as distraction and I would like to hide it.

I am not fluent in JavaScript, but I am very knowledgeable in Python and PowerShell and recently started learning C++. Normally I would just open devtools in my computer and find the element and block it with [uBlock Origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UBlock_Origin).

But as of now, I can't. I have not been contributing the past few days, because I currently being hospitalized. I am stuck in hospital and cannot use my desktop computer at my home, and I can only use my Android phone.

Having nothing better to do at all, the only pastime I had the last few days was reading the Stack Exchange sites, and the mobile version makes the related questions section more prominent and therefore more obnoxious and harder to ignore.

I only found one relevant [post](https://stackapps.com/questions/9677/remove-related-questions-from-the-middle-of-the-page), but it doesn't solve my problem, because it only hides related question in the middle bar and explicitly preserves it in the right panel, but I want to hide it wherever it is.

And second, presumably it only works for PC's and not Android. I have not tested it yet, but I want a version that is cross-platform (supports desktop and mobile).

I do have the uBlock Origin extension installed on my Firefox for Android. How can I hide related questions?

Comment: I do read "Hot Network Questions" and that's why I had to scroll down past "related" section.

Comment: find/write a userscript? the section's class is sidebar-related, you can modify the "remove middle bar related questions" userscript to also remove the ones in the sidebar

Comment: you can also ask on stackapps.com if someone else has/is willing to write such a usercript

Comment: https://github.com/MdoubleDash/SOS_Userscripts/blob/main/Hide%20related%20links.user.js

Comment: Does that extension let you manually add block rules? If so, try adding these: `##div.sidebar-related` and `###inline_related_var_a_less` and `###inline_related_see_more` And good luck with your recovery!