# How can I hide optionally right side panel at stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support, stack-exchange, sidebar

Is there a built-in way to hide right-side panel (with links and blog entities) when reading answers to questions at [stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com)?

It takes significant place on screen and makes text and code too narrow when I work on code reviews, for example, and need to switch between code and IDE often, so I'd like them both on screen simultaneously.

Is there a natural way to hide temporarily this right-side panel to free up space on screen? I don't want to use any side plug-ins from security considerations.

Comment: According to this, one should be able to hide left navigation bar: [How can I remove or hide the left navigation bar?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/311236)
Here are some older posts discussing the right sidebar: [Stack Exchange on a small resolution screen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/321062) and [How to hide entire sidebar except for question stats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303470).

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392332/how-can-i-hide-related-questions-section-in-all-sites

Comment: If you don't want to use a userstyle extension, you can [apply user CSS directly in Firefox](https://davidwalsh.name/firefox-user-stylesheet).

Comment: @wizzwizz4, thanks, this is an interesting option. The only missing part is the respective CSS.

Comment: You can find that in the links @Martin posted, specifically [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303470).